# Navigation problem with COB3, DWAPlanerROS create Fail

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to navigate COB3 using cob_navigation_global.

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04.5, ROS-Indigo
I have launched COB3 in Gazebo using cob_bringup_sim
and then when I am trying to launch

```
roslaunch cob_navigation_global 2dnav_ros_dwa.launch
```

I am getting error like

```
[ INFO] [1500056989.693549168, 7.436000000]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[FATAL] [1500056989.982608166, 7.472000000]: Failed to create the dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS with base class type nav_core::BaseLocalPlanner does not exist. Declared types are  base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS eband_local_planner/EBandPlannerROS
[move_base-53] process has died [pid 5150, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/move_base/move_base cmd_vel:=base/twist_mux/command_navigation odom:=base/odometry_controller/odometry __name:=move_base __log:=/home/shaon/.ros/log/3b552036-68c2-11e7-92c7-184f32ad4b7f/move_base-53.log].
log file: /home/shaon/.ros/log/3b552036-68c2-11e7-92c7-184f32ad4b7f/move_base-53*.log
```

NOTE: Before everything was working perfectly, For some reason I had to reinstall ubuntu and all other things like ros-indigo etc. from then it is not working anymore. I have tried reinstall everything again. But no luck

Any idea??

Thanks in advance

Shaon Debnath

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266411/navigation-problem-with-cob3,-dwaplanerros-create-fail/) by [Shaon Debnath](https://answers.ros.org/users/30784/shaon-debnath/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2017-07-14

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

DWA is not installed.
`sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-dwa-local-planner`

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2017-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shaon Debnath](https://answers.ros.org/users/30784/shaon-debnath/) on 2017-07-14**:
Thanks David, you saved my day :) It is working now...
But I am receiving some other error, which was not before..

```
[ INFO] [1500067204.859911323, 89.950000000]: Got new plan
[ WARN] [1500067204.936564734, 89.962000000]: DWA planner failed to produce path.
```

can you identify the reason?

**Comment by [Qusai](https://answers.ros.org/users/41724/qusai/) on 2019-08-31**:
thanks very much

**Comment by [joaoquintas](https://answers.ros.org/users/3707/joaoquintas/) on 2020-09-14**:
thank you so much... the same applies to Turtlebot3 simulations with ros-melodic, the package still the same, just had to change the distro.